# javascript function to minimise boxes - start boxes minimised

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I am using a template that had some features that I liked. One of these is a table that can be minimised on a button click using the code below.

```
    $('.btn-minimize').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(this).parent().parent().next('.box-content');
    if($target.is(':visible')) $('i',$(this)).removeClass('chevron-up').addClass('chevron-down');
    else                       
    $('i',$(this)).removeClass('chevron-down').addClass('chevron-up');

    $target.slideToggle();
});
```

The only problem is that I have a few of these that I would like to start as minimised as they won't be used often.

I tired using an alert to see what data was held in $target and then maybe use an onload function to minimise them.

All i got was 'object Object' for every box.

Is there anyway to be able to identify certain boxes or if not at least have them all start minimised.

Thanks

HTML for box is

```
                <div class="box black span4" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span3">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h2><i class="halflings-icon white list"></i><span class="break"></span>Sectors</h2>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon white chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                                        <ul class="dashboard-list metro">
</div>
                </div><!--/span-->
```

Comment: conole.log is probably more useful than alert

Comment: i have checked console log but as there is no error nothing shows up. The code does what is supposed to I just want to be able to have the boxes start minimised not maximised

Comment: show the css and html for the boxes, also what is meant by using console, this `console.log('target:', $target);`

Comment: i have added the html for the boxes. If anyone can find a way just to toggle all of the boxes at once when that is triggered then that will solve my problem. Thanks